# What's the purpose of static here?

Tags: c++, c, static

In [GNU's `getopt_long` example](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html), `static` is used in a flag defined in file scope:

```
/* Flag set by ‘--verbose’. */
static int verbose_flag;
```

and in the `long_options` struct defined in a `while` loop block scope:

```
static struct option long_options[]
```

Is `static` used here so that other files cannot access the variables? Is `static` being used the same way in both cases, and is it more efficient in the struct because it is kept in the same place of memory and not reinitialized?

Answer (score 2):

If `static` is used for a variable in a file scope, it means that it's local to that file. Without that keyword, you could be able to use it in another file with `extern` keyword.

The same applies for functions. If a function in C is static in a file, it can be used only in that file and not in other files.

So yes, I guess it's to prevent using it in other files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when static appears out of any block of code in a C/C++ file, it's a declaration modifier indicates that this variable cannot be access by other file; when static appears in a block of code, it's saying that this variable is "static". verbose_flag fits in the former while long_options fits in another.

Comment: It would be better to talk about translation units than files. Translation unit is basically what is left after preprocessor, so it has all the code from all the .h files too. And `static` declaration in a .h file creates an independent copy of the thing in every translation unit where that .h file got included. So it's inaccurate/misleading to say "cannot be access by other file".

Comment: @hyde Why don't you write your own answer? Sure, suggesting improvements is fine, but comments don't really help the discussion itself.

Answer (score 0):

I will do it in the reverse order :

```
static struct option long_options[]
```

is used for the variable option to be declared once and for all independently how many time the `while` loop will be executed.

But you should see it as a whole (extracted from your link) :

```
...
while (1)
{
...
 static struct option long_options[] =
    {
      /* These options set a flag. */
      {"verbose", no_argument,       &verbose_flag, 1},  // <-- IMPORTANT HERE !
      {"brief",   no_argument,       &verbose_flag, 0},  // <-- IMPORTANT HERE !
      /* These options don’t set a flag.
         We distinguish them by their indices. */
      {"add",     no_argument,       0, 'a'},
      {"append",  no_argument,       0, 'b'},
      {"delete",  required_argument, 0, 'd'},
      {"create",  required_argument, 0, 'c'},
      {"file",    required_argument, 0, 'f'},
      {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
...
}
...
```

And, as your declaration reference a variable, in this case `verbose_flag`, it should be available over the iterations, otherwise you will loose the variable over the next iteration and then reference something that doesn't exists anymore, that would be undefined behaviour. That is why `verbose_flag` is global to the file. It is made static to ensure the variable is only usable from this file and not from another.

Comment: `verbose_flag` is in the file scope, so it would not lose it's value between iterations even without `static`. It's made `static` for a different reason...

Comment: @hyde I was about to comment the same thing

Comment: @hyde yes you are right, then it is made for the variable to be completly local to this file, ensuring there is no use from other files.